# Cannot access ubuntu from windows

Tags: networking, windows, samba, ping

I cannot access my ubuntu shared folders and I cannot ping it too (from windows). In ubuntu, I have smbd and nmbd services started. The ubuntu machine can be seen in the windows Network directory. The router's DHCP table can see the IP of both machines. I am not using any virtualization, these are two different machines. I can ping the ip of the windows machine and access its shared directories from the ubuntu. There are no firewalls on both machines.

Here is the result of `ifconfig`. eth1 is the wireless LAN. i think it is suppposed to be wlan0 but that is what appeared after installation.

[image]

Here is the smb.conf file http://pastebin.com/fd5Sag59
At the bottom of smb.conf is the shared directory.

Here are the routes

[image]

Here is the screenshot of the `ipconfig` in windows

[image]

UPDATE:

I modified my smb.conf it still didn't work

http://pastebin.com/EmUSm2DY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it by fixing a static ip to ubuntu and creating an arp entry in windows